# I am using flutter bottomNavigatonBar widget, Is there anything which it can be raised?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[This is what I want !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JphKx.png)

```
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          notchMargin: 4.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

I want the Nav bar to be slightly raised from the bottom and have rounded border. Currently it's sitting in the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I think you are looking for this ... https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want. However, I suggest you not to use `IconButton` but `FlatButton` instead as they're much simpler to work with and IconButton's width and height cannot be overridden as far as I know so when you press on your IconButton with the container wrapped by it, it will look very off.

But for your solution, wrap your IconButton with a container and use the `decoration` property to add a shadow and give a raised effect.

```
    Container(
      width: 100,
      decoration : BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        color: Colors.red,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 2, offset: Offset(5,5))

        ]

      ),
      child: IconButton(
        color: Colors.green,
        icon : Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        onPressed : (){
          //
        }
      ),
    )
```

This is the output:

[image]

You can change the `offset` property to adjust the direction of the shadow.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Fancy Navigation bar](https://pub.dev/packages/fancy_bottom_navigation) if you want that output you can just remove the text by putting an empty text to its title.